# how to code : sum_{n=1}^{100}\frac{2^{n}}{(n-1), in R

Tags: r

```
sum_{n=1}^{100}\frac{2^{n}}{(n-1)
```

I tried substituting parenthesis over curly brackets, which shows an error message. I am a beginner in R. With the problem above, I do not understand the requirements to produce code.

Comment: Are you sure the sum begins from 1, as `n=1` corresponds to Inf.

Comment: `n = 1:100; sum(2^n / (n - 1))` would work fine, thought as Peace says the `/ (n - 1)` results in infinity when `n` is 1.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, you can try something like this

```
myfunc <- function(n) 2^n/(n-1)
sum(myfunc(1:100))
```